# how to access a django sqlite3 database from command line?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm using an sqlite3 database for a django app, and it works correctly. I can print the version used with this code i wrote inside a view:

```
# views.py
import sqlite3
def my_view(..):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('C:/path/to/db.sqlite3')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT sqlite_version();')
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    sqlite_version = result[0]
    print("SQLite version:", sqlite_version) 
    ...
```

But if i run from command line `python manage.py dbshell` i get
`CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.`

There are similar questions but the answers for example suggests to download sqlite3 which i don't think it makes sense because I can see that I already have a version installed

Using: Django 4.2, Python 3.10.4, sqlite3 3.37.2. In a virtual environment.

Comment: Are you sure you sourced the venv before running the command? Maybe you are running it using the native python interpreter?

Comment: @Gameplay for sourcing the venv you mean activating it? if so, yes ( I've also tried with my native python interpeter but still the same error)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run **`python manage.py dbshell`**, you must install a database client in your system. For example, if you are using PostgreSQL, you must download and install PostgreSQL. The same goes for SQLite. By default, it comes with Python3, but it is only a program, not a command-line tool. In order to get a command-line tool, you must download [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and install it on your system. For more details, check the Django documentation for [**`dbshell`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#dbshell).